# How to find date exist or not with input comma values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input like this

```
<input type="text" id="selecteddates" value="2018-01-11,2018-01-03,2018-01-27,2018-01-31">
```

what i want is when i click on date with datepicker and compare with above input comma date values, find if date exist or not using jquery, can anyone help me.

Comment: But you will compare it with what? Is there another variable or input with date value? Please share your attempt as a working snippet using `<>`.

Comment: another date value

Comment: As a string or date object?

Comment: Also what is the format of that date value if it is a string?

Comment: same date format like dis 2018-01-11, i clicked on date with date picker

Comment: Iam updated my question plz can you check once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date format is going to stay consistent, then just check `indexOf`

```
return selectedDates.indexOf( inputDateValue ) != -1;
```

**Demo**

```js
function checkDateExists()
{
  var inputDateValue = document.getElementById( "inputDatePicker" ).value;
  var selectedDates = document.getElementById( "selecteddates" ).value;
  //console.log( inputDateValue, selectedDates );
  if ( inputDateValue.trim().length == 0 || selectedDates.trim().length == 0 )
  {    
     return false;
  }
  return selectedDates.indexOf( inputDateValue ) != -1;
}

document.getElementById("checkDate").addEventListener( "click", function(){
   console.log( "Does date exists - " + checkDateExists());
});
```

```html
Selected Dates - <input type="text" id="selecteddates" value="2018-01-11,2018-01-03,2018-01-27,2018-01-31">
<br><br><br>
Input Date - <input type="date" id="inputDatePicker">
<br><br><br>
<button id="checkDate">Check Date</button>
```

Comment: @user3544256 You have basically changed your question from **How to check if date exists** to **Check if date exists and then do...**. Please share exactly what is missing from my answer so that I can help you without having to read the entire question again.

Comment: changed my question plz check once,  if date doesn't exist in input(comma values dates)  then append html to div, if date exist not append

Comment: @user3544256 I (along with other experts) have already shared with you a demo on how to check for the existence of the date. Please make an attempt with this and open a new question instead of modifying the existing question with the same.

Comment: sry boss, i have write code mistakenly, your code is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like following to get your requirement done.

```
$("#datepicker").on("change",function(){
     var selected = $(this).val(); // this will return the selected date of the datepicker
     var dates = $('#selecteddates').val();
     dates = dates.split(',');

     dates.forEach(function(thisDate){
         //compare the selected and the array dates in this area.
     });
});
```

The above example is a conceptual sort of an example and will need further logic to implement what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to validating all the dates in the input are meaningful date format?

The following code snippet is for this:

```
var str = '2018-01-11,2018-01-03,2018-01-27,2018-02-31';
validateDates(str);

function validateDates(dates)
{
    dates.split(',').forEach(function(item, index) {
      if (!validateDate(item)) {
          console.log('date "%s" is invalid at index %d', item, index);
      }
    });
}

function validateDate(dateStr)
{
    var d = new Date();
    var parts = dateStr.split('-');
    var fullYear = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
    var month = parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1;
    var date = parseInt(parts[2], 10);
    d.setFullYear(fullYear);
    d.setMonth(month);
    d.setDate(date);

    if (d.getFullYear() === fullYear
      && d.getMonth() === month
      && d.getDate() === date) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```